# Grails update database row exception

Tags: grails

I am using grails,and i have web application.in which when call for update user profile,then i have service for it,in which i set current user properties by request parameters

```
user.properties = params (params-request parameters),
```

and in my user domain class i have `onChange` method(of audit plugins).
So when this method called after setting properties to user profile when control goes to user domain `onChange` method it gives error

```
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.web.User#3].
```

I am still finding solution how to update row.
Thanks in advance.

```
//userController update method -     
def user = User.get(params.id)   
user.properties = params                                
user.save(flush:true)      

//and in user domain onChange method-   

  def onChange = { oldMap,newMap ->
        try{
            Msg.append("Your profile has been updated successfully with the following changes: ");
            oldMap.each({ key, oldVal ->
                if(oldVal != newMap[key]) {
                  if(key =="firstName" || key =="gender" || key =="lastName" || key =="phoneNo" || key =="city"){
                      Msg.append(" * $key changed from $oldVal to " + newMap[key])
                  }
                }
                sendMail(Msg,newMap.email)
           })          
       }
  }
```

After sending email it gives an error.

Comment: I guess you also have `static auditable = true` in User domain?

Comment: What's the content of sendMail?

Comment: What is your Project environment? production or development

Comment: i have set static auditable = true in user domain and project environment is development.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you try to set all the fields on the user object, then it will work:

```
       def user = User.get(params.id)   
       user.refresh() 
       user.firstName= params.firstName
       user.lastName= params.lastName
       user.gender= params.gender
       user.phno= params.phno
       user.city= params.city


    if(user.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)){
      // Now send success email
    }
```

Now it should work.

I think your params map is having id as a property and on setting

```
user.properties = params
```

It tries to set id for the user object, that's why you are getting the issue.

Comment: i have tried it but still same problem exist.If any other solution please suggest me.

Comment: one more error is-  Could not synchronize database state with session

Comment: add failOnError:true on the object save, and check the error.

and for the Could not synchronize database state with session, issue try object.refresh(), it may help.

Please Check out the updated answer

Comment: One more thing, for the Could not synchronize database state with session, issue, check out the answer in the question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036274/could-not-synchronize-database-state-with-session-error-while-saving-in-groovy

he suggested to change keys to String, before using them.
let see if it can help.

Comment: Today i tried it but got -org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailure Exception: Object of class [com.web.User] with identifier [2]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.web.User#2]

Comment: When i receive request for update all update object and save it.Then control goes to domain where it check changes in user object and if any change found then send mail to user.So there are two threads one work in user controller and second in domain.And i receive error after mail sent to user.

Comment: it is not working,if you have some other solution please help me.